# examples of linear map $f:V \rightarrow V$, which is injective but not surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am trying to find a linear map $f:V \rightarrow V$, which is injective but not surjective.

I always thought that if the dimension of the domain and codomain are equal and the map is injective it implies that a map is surjective. Maybe we need an infinite basis of the vector space $V$? What can be an example of that?

Thank you!

Comment: Right, you need an infinite-dimensional space. Can you think of some simple infinite dimensional vector space?

Comment: Just simple integration of functions will probably do so we will never obtain a constant, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, we need an infinite-dimensional vector space. An interesting example is: $V$ the space of continuous functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ and $f$ integration $f(g)(x)=\int_0^xg(t)\,\mathrm dt$. This is not surjective because $f(g)(0)=0$ for all $g$

Comment: Thank you! Does it mean that it is not surjective? Isn't it not injective?

Comment: @marco11: $f$ is injective, because if $g_1$ and $g_2$ differ at some point -- say $g_1(x_0)\ne g_2(x_0)$, then $f(g_1)$ and $f(g_2)$ will have different derivatives at that point, and so cannot be the same function. On the other hand $f$ is not surjective because, for example, the function $x\mapsto x+1$ is not $f(g)$ for any $g$ (namely $f(g)(0)=\int_0^0 g(t)dt = 0 \ne 0+1 $).

Answer (score 5):

In finite dimensions we have that bijectivity $\Leftrightarrow$ injectivity $\Leftrightarrow$ surjectivity. Hence we have to come up with an infinite-dimensional example. The idea is to pick a basis $v_i, i\in \mathbb N$, and shift every basis vector $v_i \mapsto v_{i+1}$. We can do that not hitting the first basis vector *only* because we have infinitely many elements.

Comment: Pick your favorite vector space of infinite countable dimension for that.

Comment: I thought it worth mentioning this is the right shift operator.