# What does the notation: function[a,b] mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

What does the notation $f[a,b]$ mean?

For example:  V the space of continuous functions $[0,1]→\mathbb{R}$

Seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1297313/529962).

I would think the interval defines either the **range** or **domain**; however, due to difficulty of googling symbols, I have been unable to find an answer.

Comment: The site you give never uses the notation $f (x)[a,b] $ which I've never seen before.  The notation $f:X\to Y$ simply means $f $ is a function that maps the domain set $X $ to $Y $.  So $f [0,1]\to \mathbb R $ simply means $f $ is a function that has any $x $ so that $0\le x\le 1$ as input and outputs a real number.

Comment: There is no notation "function $[a,b]$". The phrase "the space of continuous functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb R$" is to be interpreted as "the space of continuous functions of the type $[0,1]\to\mathbb R$", i.e. the space of continuous functions whose domain is $[0,1]$ and codomain is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Rahul I think your comment is a better answer than the existing one and should be posted as such, ideally with mention of the related notation $f:A\to B$ (with the colon)

Answer (score 0):

We usually write $f: D \to C$ where the $D$ denotes the domain and $C$ is the codomain.

here the domain of the function is $[0,1]$, the closed interval from $0$ to $1$.